# Avalonia / LibVLCsharp support for iOS, Android and WASM

Tags: audio, media-player, webassembly, avaloniaui, libvlcsharp

I'm planning to create a cross platform (Windows, Linux, macOS, Android, iOS, Wasm) audio player using latest AvaloniaUI along with LibVLCSharp. Unfortunately only support for Windows, Linux and macOS is listed for Avalonia.

I think that this might be a lack of documentation only, since Avalonia pretty recently introduced Android and iOS support officially.

So how is the state of this? Would it be possible to create a REAL cross platform player for all the listed platforms with LibVLCSharp? And if not, is there an alternative, that could be used with AvaloniaUI?

I found these libs for C#, that are (partially) capable of playing audio:

- LibVLCSharp (unmanaged/wrapper, cross platform including Android + iOS)
- SharpAudio (mostly managed, cross platform, but poor codec support atm)
- cscore (unmanaged/wrapper, well designed, development stalled)
- libsoundio-sharp (unmanaged, pretty raw)
- ManagedBass (unmanaged/wrapper for BASS, awesome but only free  for open source)
- NAudio (awesome managed library, but windows only atm, although efforts to evolve to cross platform)

Comment: if you only need audio, libvlcsharp will curently work for all your target platforms except WASM.

Comment: Great thank you... so just a lack of documentation. Would it be possible to somehow add WASM support via vlc.js? (https://code.videolan.org/jbk/vlc.js)

Comment: it would be possible yes. Open to contributors and funding.

Comment: Ok, so I would do it. If you could help me with that (I don't even know where to start), I would love open a feature request, where we can discuss the next steps for a truly cross platform media player.

Comment: you can start by trying to build vlc for the WASM target. See how the CI does it for guidance

Comment: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp/-/issues/211

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to have a real cross platform app, you indeed CAN use LibVLCSharp for the following platforms via nuget package:

- Windows
- Linux ([X11 needs extra init code](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp/-/issues/596#note_366502))
- macOS
- Android
- iOS

Also see https://github.com/videolan/libvlcsharp#installation